# Mass Edit of Cell Range in Sheets in Folder Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used this script in the past to edit a cell or range of cells in a set of spreadsheets in a specific folder (using a source file), but when I run the script it does not work.  In fact, instead of copying the range from the source sheet it clears out existing data in the destination sheets.

Here is script I have been using:

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNHFL6fMFz-LwJ4tZrvTN92foXhf7VS8").getFiles() 
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      
      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getFormulas();
      
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
      var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:A'); 
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
 }
 }
```

Here is a link to the [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NNHFL6fMFz-LwJ4tZrvTN92foXhf7VS8?usp=sharing) I have been testing this in.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem

Comment: I initially ran this script successfully two years ago, which is why I am confused.  I had it running in a folder where it was editing about 300 sheets with each run, so I have since pulled it out and into it's own test folder (linked above) to start from scratch.  I have changed names and different ranges, as well.  I thought it might be an issue with the source code file in the same directory so I have moved it around to different places to see.

Comment: Have you run it and debug mode and to see where it’s failing?

Comment: I did.  It doesn't show a failure.  It is working, although it's doing the opposite of what I would expect in that it is clearing the destination cell range instead of copying into it.

Comment: Why are you avoiding the use of the debugger that’s in the script editor?

Comment: When I run the debug function it runs and then closes.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Set a breakpoint near the beginning of the script and then single step through the script one line at a time making sure that you read all the variables and see that they’re changing correctly

Comment: You should change you range "A:A" to (row, column, number of row, number of columns) because in script the use of ranges without numbers usually results in a lot of nulls at the end of your data set that just have to be filtered out and of course your not filtering them out

Comment: I don't think the debugger will help with the issue I'm experiencing.  Right now it's working in replacing cells, but it's overwriting the new destination cells with blanks instead of the values from the source spreadsheet.  So the script is running but I'm not sure why it's inserting blanks into the destination cells

Comment: Did you read my last comment?

Answer (score 2):

Your script works fine if you change `setValues()` to `setFormulas` (if you need formulas):

```
function myFunction() {

  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNHFL6fMFz-LwJ4tZrvTN92foXhf7VS8").getFiles() 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    
    var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');
    var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getFormulas();
    
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange('A:A'); 
    destrange.setFormulas(sourcevalues); // <------------- HERE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunc() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NNHFL6fMFz-LwJ4tZrvTN92foXhf7VS8").getFiles() 
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange(1,1,sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1);
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getFormulas();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange(1,1,sourcesheet.getLastRow(),1); 
    destrange.setFormulas(sourcevalues);         
  }
}
```